# Prevent same button from being clicked multiple times in tic tac toe game

Tags: java, jbutton, tic-tac-toe

I'm making a simple tic tac toe game. In the game, whether it is x or o's turn is determined by the int `turn`. Here is a piece from the actionlistener to show how it works.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
   String command = e.getActionCommand();
   if (command.equals("b1")){
      //top row 1
      if (turn%2==0){
         b1.setText("X");
         turn ++;
         l1.setText("O's turn");
         x[0][0] = true;
      } else {
         b1.setText("O");
         turn ++;
         l1.setText("X's Turn");
         o[0][0] = true;              
      }
}
```

The issue is, that I when a button is clicked and it displays the x or o, the other player can click the same button to change the spot from an x to an o or vice versa. How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you could disable the button once it is clicked on so that it is not clickable any more:

> UPDATE

```
if (command.equals("b1")){
        //top row 1
        if (turn%2==0){
            b1.setText("X");
            //add the following

            turn ++;
            l1.setText("O's turn");
            x[0][0] = true;
            turnNum ++;
            b1.removeActionListener(this);
        }
    } else {
        b1.setText("O");
        //add the following

        turn ++;
        l1.setText("X's Turn");
        o[0][0] = true;
        b1.removeActionListener(this);


    }
```

Comment: when I add the b1.enabled(false); it gives me an error saying cannont find method enabled(boolean)

Comment: Sorry, I edited the answer, it should be setEnabled(false); It should function correctly now

Comment: it is working, but there is one other problem. I have it set so that when the button is clicked the font is red and when someone wins the font becomes blue, but with this method the font is gray. how can i make it red again

Comment: Ok I have edited the answer again, this should cater for both conditions, have a look now. You can try removing the ActionListener, so that it is not clickable but keeps the formatting that you want it to have :)

Comment: what's changed from before?

Comment: Instead of b1.setEnabled(false) try b1.removeActionListener(this);

Comment: What is the point behind having two answers in one? I'd assume the OP will end up using only one. So which one can be removed? The part before the "update"?

Comment: I understand. Edited it, so that the correct answer is remaining. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much. ive been working on a fix for this for so long. who knew it was such a simple fix. Your'e a life saver Thanks again

Comment: Not a problem, so the answer was correct? Glad I could be of assistance! Go on, tick it ;)

Comment: it did work but there is one issue. now that the actionlistener is removed the game can no longer determine winners because when the button is clicked and it removes the actionlistener the x[][] boolean is no longer set to true for that spot on the board

Comment: Oh I see, you could try changing the position where you are removing the ActionListener ... Move that line of code to after you assign your position to true .. So after this "o[0][0] = true;" ..

Comment: i have edited the answer, I moved the position of the removeActionListener. This should work now